# mapbox-navigation-android-master error on demo application

Tags: mapbox

I have try to run the mention demo application on mobile device. NavigationActivity. However after a while the application error and exit with error message below.

java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'double com.mapbox.services.android.navigation.v5.MapboxNavigationOptions.getMinimumHighAlertDistance()' on a null object reference

anybody experience the same problem? any resolution?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

When you have a `class` `MyClass` and you have a `null` object of that `class` like

```
MyClass myInstance = null;
```

and instances of `MyClass` have a method called `myMethod()`, then calling it like

```
myInstance.myMethod();
```

will result in `NullPointerException` if `myInstance` is `null`. To resolve your problem you need to do one of the following:

- put the code into a `try`-`catch` and handle the exception in the `catch`
- verify whether `myInstance` is `null` and if it is not, only then call its `myMethod`
- make sure `myInstance` will not be `null` when you intend to use its methods/members